# iOS Hide Navigation Bar when i tap Search Bar with animation

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I'm trying to hide Navigation Bar when I tap the search bar with animation, exactly how it happens in the App Store. I've already tried with the function hide navigation bar when I tap search bar, but I don't have any animation and the navigation doesn't back. I'm working with the `class extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate`

Here's an inline [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQJs0.gif)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a searchBar like the searchBar in the App Store app, you can use the UISearchController class.

You can find more informations in the Apple Developer website

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller

You can also look at this tutorial

https://www.raywenderlich.com/472-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started